# When I am trying to authorise my salesforce org, I am getting an error

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce

When I am trying to authorize my salesforce sandbox org using the command sfdx: authorize org from VS code it is giving the below error.

Invalid client credentials. Verify the OAuth client secret and ID. Error authenticating with
auth code due to: request to https://ingau--dev2.sandbox.my.salesforce.com//services/oauth2/token failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.126.23.68:443

Salesforce CLI Version - 2.11.8 win32-x64 node-v18.15.0

The issue is happening in client't desktop

1. Tried uninstall and installing again the both Salesforce CLI and VS code
2. Tried by using the customer URL i.e. My domain URL
3. Tried setting up the variable NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0
4. Tried connecting to Network and IT team, But there are no logs captured from their end which says something is blocking
5. disconnected the VPN and Tried but no luck
6. tried setting up the proxy variables as mentioned in the below document but still the same error

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.